# Convert from Map to Set in Spring Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to convert from Map to Set in Cassandra

```
  @CassandraType(type = Name.SET)
  private Map<Integer, Address> addresses;
```

Address is my UDT.

```
@UserDefinedType(value = "address")
public class Address
```

I am getting this error.

Can some one help me to fox this

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'session' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/cassandra/CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Expected [1] typed arguments for property ['addresses'] of type ['interface java.util.Map']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you intend to convert `Set` to a `Map`. Cassandra columns must be represented with their according data types in entity classes.

If you want to apply conversion then you need to handle this aspect within your code. Simply remove `@CassandraType(type = Name.SET)`.